# How to write driver.page_source to a binary file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, unicode

I'm using selenium to download an xls from a website.  Selenium clicks on a button, and the result is that `driver.page_source` now contains the Excel spreadsheet.

How to extract the value of driver.page_source into a binary file, that I can open in Excel, libreoffice, et al?

If I just try to write this to a file, I get issues with ascii encoding and so on.  I tried converting it to a bytearray first, but it still seems to want some kind of encoding, and 'utf-8' doesn't produce a working excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be the most elegant solution, but what worked for me, eventually, was to simply write each byte, one by one, like this:

```
f = open('report.xls', 'wb')
for uchar in driver.page_source:
    f.write(bytearray([ord(uchar)]))
f.close()
```

This produced a working Excel file, which I could then open in libreoffice et al.